# "На всём свете" и "во всём свете" стилистически синонимичны?

Tags: лексика, синонимы, архаизмы

> Не рекомендую вам и модные **во всём свете** китайские рестораны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Не рекомендую вам и модные во всём свете китайские рестораны**

"Модные на всем свете" не звучит. Думаю, если нечто находится/происходит везде, нужно говорить "во всем свете".

Answer (score 1):

На всём свете правильнее употреблять когда говорится о самом-самом и акцент сделан на сам объект. Например: эта башня самая высокая на свете.
Во всём свете, на мой взгляд, вернее употребить когда акцент делается факт "всемирности". Примером вполне может стать ваше предложение.